# VB.net WPF DataGrid ObservableCollection Binding property update

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, observablecollection

I am using VB.NET and WPF within Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Currently, I have:

- A DataGrid by the name of *downloadListDG*. This has a column which is a template containing an image.
- An *ObservableCollection* of a custom *DownloadListItem* class.
- This *DownloadListItem* has a public property which is another custom class.
- This class has a private dim which is a StateType (a custom enum), and a public readonly property which returns a string depending on what the StateType is (actually an image URI if you're curious).
- The *DownloadListItem* also has a public property which just returns the StateType (this is just for binding purposes)

My problem is that whenever the StateType changes, the image column in the DataGrid does not change. I have been trying to use the *IPropertyChangedNofity*, but nothing changes, so either I'm using it incorrectly or I need to use another method.

```
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

AddHandler ControllerRef.StateChanged, AddressOf StateChangeHandler

Private Sub StateChangeHandler(NewState As State)
    MsgBox(NewState)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentState"))
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the PropertyChanged event is notifying the UI of the property name you are bound to, not the property that triggers the change. Example:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
```

Public Class DownloadListItem : Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
Friend Enum StateEnum
    State1 = 0
    State2 = 1
End Enum

Private _CurrentState As StateEnum

Private Sub ChangeEnumValue(NewValue As StateEnum)
    _CurrentState = NewValue
    OnPropertyChanged("ImageURI")
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property ImageURI As String
    Get
        ' TODO: Implement conditional logic to return proper value based on CurrentState Enum
    End Get
End Property

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank-you very much!